# svg hexagon halftone pattern

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been searching google but there is no answers or articles to this question. I want to create a grid of hexagons but I need it in a halftone pattern, so I might need more than one hexagon in the pattern. Below is the code that generates a pattern of hexagons but not in halftone pattern. I need the halftone pattern to go horizontally. I have this [link](https://stock.adobe.com/nz/images/honeycomb-halftone-vector-abstract-background-halftone-effect-repeating-background-texture/152449673) of the halftone pattern from adobe but the grid is too small and it goes vertically but I want it horizontally. Here is a link of the grid of hexagons I made on [codepen](https://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/orEYZr?editors=0110). Could someone show me to make a pattern of hexagons go horizontally in a halftone pattern, please?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}
svg {
  background: rgb(125, 155, 132);
}

polygon {
  fill: rgb(125, 155, 132);
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
         <defs>
            <pattern id="hexagons" width="50" height="43.4" 
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
            patternTransform="scale(2)">
                <polygon 
                points="24.8,22 37.3,29.2 37.3,43.7 24.8,50.9 12.3,43.7 12.3,29.2" 
                id="hex" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" />
                <use xlink:href="#hex" x="25" />
                <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-25" />
                <use xlink:href="#hex" x="12.5" y="-21.7" />
                <use xlink:href="#hex" x="-12.5" y="-21.7" />
            </pattern>
         </defs>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#hexagons)" />
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 7):

Since the radiuses of the hexagons are a variable of x you can't use patterns here.
the main idea is this:

- the svg background is white;
- the hexagons have `fill:black;`
- in order to draw the hexagons you need to calculate the center of the of the circumscribed circle. You do it using the value of the radius of the circumscribed circle `R`. This is generating a hexagonal lattice.
- Inside the hexagonal lattice you need to change the radius of the of the circumscribed circle for the hexagons in function of y like this: `let r = R * Math.sin(angle)` where the angle is in function of the x value and  calculates like this: `let angle = map(x, 0, H, 0, Math.PI);` This means that the `x` is taking a value between 0 and 200 (`H`) and the angle will have a value between o and Math.PI.

Please read the comments in my code.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
// variables used to draw the hexagon stack
let R = 5;// the radius of the circumscribed circle
let h = R * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3);//half height of the hexagon
let offset = 1.5 * R;//used to offset every second row of hexagons
let W = 200,H=200;//svg's viewBox = "0 0 200 200"

//draw the hexagonal lattice
let i = 0;
for(let y = 0; y<H; y+=h){
i++
let o = (i%2 == 0) ? offset : 0;
for(let x = o; x<W; x+=3*R){
  hex(x,y)
}
}


 // a function used to draw the hexagom
 // the radius of the hexagon depends on the x value
 function hex(x,y) {
    // the radius of the drawn hexagon is in function of the x value
    let angle = map(x, 0, H, 0, Math.PI);
    let r = R * Math.sin(angle) - .5
   
    let points = ""
    for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
      let o = {}
      o.x = x + r * Math.cos(a * Math.PI / 3);
      o.y = y + r * Math.sin(a * Math.PI / 3);
      points+= `${o.x}, ${o.y} `
    } 
   
     let hexagon = drawSVGelmt({points:points},"polygon", svg)
  }



// a function used to draw a new svg element
function drawSVGelmt(o,tag, parent) {
  
  let elmt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, tag);
  for (let name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      elmt.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(elmt);
  return elmt;
}


function map(n, a, b, _a, _b) {
  let d = b - a;
  let _d = _b - _a;
  let u = _d / d;
  return _a + n * u;
}
```

```css
svg{background:white; border:1px solid;width:90vh;}
polygon{fill:black}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox = "0 0 200 200" >  
</svg>
```

## UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> Thats kinda what I want but I'm trying to make a pattern so I can then use that patter for a mask for an image

and latter:

> basically what you have made works but I need the pattern to repeat across the page becuase the image will be 100% width and about 800px height

In this case you can put all the hexagons in a group and use `clipPath` to clip the group like so:

```js
var SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
let H = 800,W=500
var R = 5;
//var l = R;
var h = R * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3);
var offset = 1.5 * R;



let i = 0;
for(let y = 0; y<H; y+=h){
i++
let o = (i%2 == 0) ? offset : 0;
for(let x = o; x<W; x+=3*R){
  hex(x,y)
}
}

 function hex(x,y) {
    let angle = map(x, 0, W, 0, Math.PI);
    let r = R * Math.sin(angle) - .5
   
    let points = ""
    for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
      let o = {}
      o.x = x + r * Math.cos(a * Math.PI / 3);
      o.y = y + r * Math.sin(a * Math.PI / 3);
      points+= `${o.x}, ${o.y} `
    } 
   
     let hexagon = drawSVGelmt({points:points},"polygon", svg)
  }




function drawSVGelmt(o,tag, parent) {
  
  let elmt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, tag);
  for (let name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      elmt.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(elmt);
  return elmt;
}


function map(n, a, b, _a, _b) {
  let d = b - a;
  let _d = _b - _a;
  let u = _d / d;
  return _a + n * u;
}
```

```css
svg{background:white; border:1px solid;}
polygon{fill:black}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 500 800" > 
<clipPath  id="clip">
  <polygon points="250,0 100,100 0 300 100,600 200,800 400,600 500,500 400,200 250,0"/>
</clipPath>
  
<g id="svg" style="clip-path: url(#clip)"></g>
</svg>
```

And if you don't specify the width of the svg element, it will take all the width available i.e: 100%.

Comment: Great answer! but the author writes: `it goes vertically but I want it horizontally`.

Comment: LOL, Thank you so much @Alexandr_TT!!! The fix was easy: I've changed `let angle = map(y, 0, H, 0, Math.PI);` with `let angle = map(x, 0, H, 0, Math.PI);`.  Now the radius of the drawn hexagon is in function of the `x` value

Comment: Thats kinda what I want  ut I'm trying to make a pattern so I can then use that patter for a mask for an image

Comment: No I would need photoshop, but basically what you have made works but I need the pattern to repeat across the page becuase the image will be 100% width and about 800px height

Comment: So the svg needs to be 100% width

Comment: You have the right idea but I need to make the pattern go across and repeat it self, I've set up an codepen of what you did but put it in a pattern, I need to make the hexagon pattern repeat across the page, how do I do that https://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/wLyjMO

Comment: I've made a fork of your pen. Please take a look: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/LKQmdm

Comment: Ok it's looking better but I need more hexagons in the white area so there needs to be more spacing between the clusters of he pattern, I need more hexagons in the white space, what did you do or change to get that pattern to go across what properties to you change

Comment: Ive added the mask and got that working, I just need to make the pattern spread out more in the blank spaces, how do I adjust the spread of the hexagons https://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/KjQRbg?editors=0100

Comment: In this case you may want to constrain the value of the r used inside the function hex() between a minim and a maxim value

Answer (score 3):

<sup>The values used aren't very precise. I am focusing on the technique rather than the calculation.</sup>

Here is an idea combining SVG and multiple background. The trick is to have a different SVG at each row where each time you increase the stroke and then you consider some radial background.

I considered some CSS variables to easily adjust the shape:

```css
body {  
  height: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  margin: 0;
  --s:9.65vh;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50.1%;
  background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="15" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>');
  background-size:auto var(--s);
  background-position:
    0        calc(0*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(1*var(--p)),
    0        calc(2*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(3*var(--p)),
    0        calc(4*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(5*var(--p)),
    0        calc(6*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(7*var(--p));
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleY(-1);
  transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

[image: CSS Hexagon pattern halftone]

We can invert the coloration by chaging the SVG colors:

```css
body {  
  height: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  margin: 0;
  --s:9.65vh;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50.1%;
  background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="15" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>');
  background-size:auto var(--s);
  background-position:
    0        calc(0*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(1*var(--p)),
    0        calc(2*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(3*var(--p)),
    0        calc(4*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(5*var(--p)),
    0        calc(6*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(7*var(--p));
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleY(-1);
  transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

[image: CSS Hexagon pattern halftone]

And also invert the pattern by changing `background-position`

```css
body {  
  height: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  margin: 0;
  --s:9.65vh;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50.1%;
  background: 
     url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="15" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 216 240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="113,5 221,67.5 221,172.5 113,235 5,172.6 5,67.5" /></svg>');
  background-size:auto var(--s);
  background-position:
    var(--x) calc(7*var(--p)),
    0        calc(6*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(5*var(--p)),
    0        calc(4*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(3*var(--p)),
    0        calc(2*var(--p)),
    var(--x) calc(1*var(--p)),
    0        calc(0*var(--p));
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleY(-1);
  transform-origin:bottom;
}
```

[image: CSS Hexagon pattern halftone]

---

For the horizontal pattern we do the same considering `repeat-y` and by inverting almost all the values:

```css
body {  
  width: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  height:150vh;
  margin:0;
  --s:9.65vw;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:50.1%;
  background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="15" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "transparent" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="black" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>');
  background-size:var(--s) auto ;
  background-position:
    calc(7*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(6*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(5*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(4*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(3*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(2*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(1*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(0*var(--p)) 0;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleX(-1);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

[image: CSS Hexagon pattern halftone]

```css
body {  
  width: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  height:150vh;
  margin:0;
  --s:9.35vw;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:50.1%;
  background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="15" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>');
  background-size:var(--s) auto ;
  background-position:
    calc(7*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(6*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(5*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(4*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(3*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(2*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(1*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(0*var(--p)) 0;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleX(-1);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

[image: CSS Hexagon pattern halftone]

```css
body {  
  width: calc(10.35*var(--s));
  height:150vh;
  margin:0;
  --s:9.35vw;
  --p:calc(var(--s)*0.667);
  --x:calc(var(--s)*1.35);
  position:relative;
}

body:before,
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:50.1%;
  background: 
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>') 0 0,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="15" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="80%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="90%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="70%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="80%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="50%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="60%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>'),
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 2 240 216" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><radialGradient id="g"><stop stop-color = "black" offset="30%"/><stop stop-color="transparent" offset="40%"/></radialGradient></defs><polygon fill="url(%23g)" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" points="5,113 67.5,221 172.5,221 235,113 172.6,5 67.5,5" /></svg>');
  background-size:var(--s) auto ;
  background-position:
    calc(0*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(1*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(2*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(3*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(4*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(5*var(--p)) 0,
    calc(6*var(--p)) var(--x),
    calc(7*var(--p)) 0;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

body:after {
  transform:scaleX(-1);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

[image: CSS Hexagon pattern halftone]

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on enxaneta's and your comments.

For repeats, you can change the times Math.Pi/3 is multiplied in :

```
let angle = map(x, 0, boxW, 0, repeats * Math.PI);
```

To constrain the r value in the function hex() you can set a minW var and add :

```
if (c <= minW && c > -minW) {
    r = R * minW;
  } else {
    r = R * c;
  }
```

for max value/space between hex, you add a spacing var and :

```
if (c <= minW && c > -minW) {
    r = R * minW - spacing;
  } else if (c < -minW) {
    r = R * c + spacing
  } else {
    r = R * c - spacing;
  }
```

you can also control the space between hex to scale with the R value, for that I added a spread var and changed these lines to :

```
point.x = x + r * Math.sin(a * Math.PI / 3) / spread;
point.y = y + r * Math.cos(a * Math.PI / 3) / spread;
```

Then to actually use the pattern to make a mask I made a funtion like :

```
function makeHexRow_pattern(){
  var patternH = 2*hexH+0.01; //*2 for 2 rows; +0.01 to avoid gab between pattern repeats
  hexPattern.setAttributeNS(null, "height", patternH); //set height of the pattern elmt
  var counter = 0;
  for (let y = 0; y < patternH; y += hexH) {
    let rowOffset = counter % 2 == 0 ? xOffset : 0;
    counter++
    for (let x = rowOffset; x < boxW; x += xOffset * 2) {
      let hexPoints = hex(x, y);
      drawSVGelmt( {points : hexPoint}, "polygon", hexagons);
    }
  }
}
```

I added the vars repeat, minW, spacing, spread at the begining to make it easier to customize.

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/salixdubois/pen/BgvRRR)

Comment: updated the image link, was broken. If there's no image, it means it broke again, just change it in the html.